# javascript date issue with timezone

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I'm converting a string date to date object but getting one day less. I googled but couldn't understand how to change get proper output. Can anyone help me or give me a reference where I can understand from.

```
new Date("2001-02-03")
```

browser resut: `Fri Feb 02 2001 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST).`

expected: `Fri Feb 03 2001 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST).`

Comment: which browser you are using ?

Comment: Mine is chrome browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser represents JS dates with the system's timezone taken into account. The given date string has no time portion so it assumes `00:00:00` for time. You appear to be in the `-05:00` timezone, so the date will be represented five hours behind your specified time which is 7pm the previous day. You can use `toUTCString()` to see the date information w/o timezone.

```
var d = new Date("2001-02-03");
d.toUTCString()
"Sat, 03 Feb 2001 00:00:00 GMT"
```

or in a shorter form

```
(new Date("2001-02-03")).toUTCString()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. can't I convert the result to date object? I mean i want result of toUTCString() as date object.

Comment: Your date object's internal datetime pointer is at `Sat, 03 Feb 2001 00:00:00 GMT`. There's nothing to convert. It will always be represented according to timezone unless you specify not to.